# Homomorphic Secret Sharing

Tags: solidity, blockchain, cryptography, encryption

Speaking of Ethereum blockchain, Is it possible to perform homomorphic secret sharing algorithmic calculations like SSS/pVSS/VSS on-chain? or should this be calculations performed off-chain

Comment: Could you provide a user case? The question is too broad